# Excel 2016 -calculating average,median,max,mean based on category in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[image: my spreadsheet]
Hi, I want to calculate average,median,max,mean for every single 'type' in the table by itself. How do I do it ? It seemed to me like a very simple task and yet I'm struggling with it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use AVERAGEIF, MAXIFS, MINIFS and IF in combination with MEDIAN.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I've seen averageif but I don't see a formula named maxifs or minifs

Comment: MAXIFS and MINFS are in Excel2019, 2021 and 365. I didn't see that your version is 2016. Try to use IF in combination  with MAX and MIN to get the results

Comment: I tried and didnt succeed, that's why i asked here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For average of a group in Excel 2016, you can use `AVERAGEIF`. For the other statistics, you use this pattern:

`{=STAT(IF(group_range=group,data_range))}`

Where `STAT` is the chosen statistical function (In your case, one of `MEDIAN`, `MIN` or `MAX`). Note that the braces `{...}` are to indicate that this is an array formula. They are not typed into the formula bar or the cell. You type the formula, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and this converts your formula to an array formula.

So:
[image]

The formulas in column E:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$13,E$1,$B$2:$B$13)
{=MEDIAN(IF($A$2:$A$13=E$1,$B$2:$B$13))}
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=E$1,$B$2:$B$13))}
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$13=E$1,$B$2:$B$13))}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly - the part I had missing was the ARRAY FORMULA that I didn't know existed. Could you just edit your answer and put the sentence 'They are not typed into the formula bar or the cell' in bold ? I'm sure it will help future users seeking for the answer...